# Android namespece not found in c# using statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-sdk-tools

I have launced a c# xamarin.forms project that I haven't used for a while and Visual Studio is saying that the `using Android.App` is not found.  The Android namespace has the red underline.  This was working the last time I used it and now it's giving this error.  The code that was using this was the Application(Icon...):

```
using Android.App;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

How can I get the Android namespace into my project?  Is it related to the SDK's?  Android SDK Platform 34 is showing as installed in Visual Studio.  Visual studio suggests adding a reference to mono.android.dll, but there is already a reference.  I'm just not sure if this is an issue with it using the wrong version, or I have some corrupt file in the project (I have pulled the repo to another laptop and got the same issue)

The issue is in multiple classes too.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: How did you add it originally? A using statement references a library which is a dll. Some libraries are registered and will be found automatically.  Child projects the dll gets copies to the bin folder as specified in the csproj file. When you do a clean build all the dlls in the bin folder get deleted and then gets copied per the csproj instructions.  Errors like this occur when you manually copy a file to the bin without adding the instruction to the csproj.  Normally I put the dll in the main c# project folder.  Then using menu Add Existing item browse for dll which will do copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to troubleshoot this problem by following the steps below:

1.recheck if some special class in your solution has a namespace conflict between several libraries.

2.try to delete the obj folders and bin folders of every platform, then rebuild it.

3.if this problem persists, try to update your nugets of your solution to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.  The path to Mono.Android.dll is different **depending on which version of visual studio you are running**

Project was originally created in VS Professional.  Opening in Community on a different machine couldn't find the dll:

```
\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\**2022\Community**\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v11.0\Mono.Android.dll
```

Because there was already a reference to Mono.Android.dll, the intellisense couldn't tell there was an issue.